# OpenDialog always returns false on Win10

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I have a 32-bit application built with C++Builder 10.1.2.  It has a `TFileOpenDialog` component.  Under Windows 7, it works fine, but when run on Windows 10, either from the file browser or the debugger, its `Execute()` method always returns `false`.

`TFileOpenDialog` is a Vista component, so I replaced it with a `TOpenDialog`, and its `Execute()` method always returns `false`, too.

I know it's a long shot, but what could we be missing?

Comment: What returns false? TOpenDialog is a class, classes don't return.

Comment: Sorry, the Execute function returns false.  This should happen only if the Cancel button is pressed.

Comment: Do you actually have access to the file selected? Try to run your app **as Administrator** (being logged as one is not enough) I got similar problems with accessing driver/service files on newer win7 installations (old ones was working OK).

Comment: "*This should happen only if the Cancel button is pressed*" - it also happens if the dialog itself fails. Do you see the dialog appear onscreen at all, or does `Execute()` returns false immediately?

Comment: Also note that on Vista+, by default `TOpenDialog` uses the same `IFileOpenDialog` interface that `TFileOpenDialog` uses, unless you take extra steps to disable that behavior.